# MVVM: ViewModels for bidirectional model elements

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Assume I have following Model structure:

```
class Team {
    public string Name {get;set; }
    public List<Player> players {get;set;}
}

class Player {
    public int Age {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public Team Team {get;set;}
}
```

I wish to create Viewmodels for this model. However, I also would like to avoid duplicating all properties from Player in the TeamVM and vice versa (for this simple example this would be feasable, but in reality rather cumbersome).

Looking at the literature and online articles, it seems that the "Pure" way would be to create a ViewModel for each Model and to have a ViewModel only return other ViewModels and never Models. This is all fine, but my problem is: how do you create these viewmodels without getting into a recursion trap. Assume I do it like this:

```
public class TeamVM: ViewModel<Team> {

   private ObservableCollection<PlayerVM> _players;

   public TeamVM(Team t): base(t) {
       _players = new ObservableCollection();
       foreach (Player p in t.players) {
          _players.Add(new PlayerVM(t));
       }
   }

   public string Name {
      get { return _modelElement.Name; }
      set { _modelElement.Name = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
   }

   public ObservableCollection<PlayerVM> Players {
      get { return _players; }
   }
}
```

and

```
public class PlayerVM : ViewModel<Player> {

   private TeamVM _teamVM;

   public PlayerVM(Player p): base(p) {
       _teamVm = new TeamVM(p.Team);
   }

   public int Age {
      get { return _modelElement.Age; }
      set { _modelElement.Age = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
   }
   public string Name {
      get { return _modelElement.Name; }
      set { _modelElement.Name = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
   }
   public TeamVM Team {
      get { return _teamVM; }
      set { _teamVm = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
   }
}
```

Obviously, the above can never work, since it creates recursion: creation of a TeamVM results in the creation of PlayerVMs which in turn spawn TeamVMs again etc.

Right now, I have solved this, by adding an intermediate class as follows:

```
public class TeamMinimalVM: ViewModel<Team> {

   public TeamVM(Team t): base(t) {
   }

   public string Name {
      get { return _modelElement.Name; }
      set { _modelElement.Name = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
   }
}

public class TeamVM: TeamMinimalVM {

   private ObservableCollection<PlayerVM> _players;

   public TeamVM(Team t): base(t) {
       _players = new ObservableCollection();
       foreach (Player p in t.players) {
          _players.Add(new PlayerVM(t));
       }
   }
}
```

And then having PlayerVM depend on TeamMinimalVM instead of TeamVM. This means that in the views, you would be able to do: {Binding Player.Team.Name} but not {Binding Player.Team.Players.Name}, which is kind of ok for me I guess since I don't think it's a great idea to do this anyway.

My question now is: is there a better/more "standard" way to do "Pure" VMs of bidirectional model elements? I do not want to clone properties of one type in the other (there are too many), nor do I want to expose Model elements directly.

Finally, the ViewModel class I use is this one (just for completeness, but it is not essential to the question I think.)

```
public class ModelElementViewModel<T> : ObservableObject where T : class 
{
    private bool _modelElementChanged;
    private T _modelElement;

    public ModelElementViewModel(T element)
    {
        _modelElement = element;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The underlying model element for this viewmodel. Protected as one should not bind directly to model elements from the gui.
    /// </summary>
    internal T ModelElement {
        get { return _modelElement; }
        set {
            if (_modelElement != value)
            {
                _modelElement = value;
                ModelElementChanged = false;
                NotifyAllPropertiesChanged();
            }
            ; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Property that can be used to see if the underlying modelelement was changed through this viewmodel (note that an external 
    /// change to the model element is not tracked!)
    /// </summary>
    public bool ModelElementChanged {
        private set
        {
            if (_modelElementChanged != value)
            {
                _modelElementChanged = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return _modelElementChanged;
        }
    }

    protected override void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        ModelElementChanged = true;
        base.NotifyPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }

}
```

**Edit:**

What wasn't clear from my original question is that Players are not used exclusively by teams. I want following three scenarios to work:

1. I want to be able to create a view for a single player that displays all player information
2. I want to be able to create a view for a team, displaying the information of that team and a table of all players with their statistics
3. I also want to be able, for example, to have a Playersbook view, which consists of a table displaying all known players with their teamname for example.

Comment: _"Looking at the literature and online articles, it seems that the "Pure" way would be to create a ViewModel for each Model"_ - that's incorrect.  You create ViewModel for each view not for each moddel.  The VM might be responsible for aggregating many models for example.  The VM's job is to supply information to the View

Comment: @MickyD: I agree with the basic idea of your comment, but it still leaves the question of how to represent the "player" data. There is likely the view that represents the team, but also a view to represent individual players (e.g. a template used for an `ItemsControl` or something). What do you suggest that player view and its view model look like?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really understand the question. I mean, the proposed answer so far suggests what I think is the obvious solution -- just pass the `TeamVM` reference to the `PlayerVM` constructor instead of having the `PlayerVM` object create a new one (optionally comparing the `TeamVM.Team` property to the `Player.Team` value to make sure the relationship is valid) -- but since it seems so obvious, it's not clear to me why you're not doing it that way. There is also the question as to why the `PlayerVM` object needs the `TeamVM` object anyway. What's the point of that?

Comment: @MickyD I agree with your statement. My starting point for creating VMs is the views I need. However, in that particular sentence, I meant that when building the VM, the "purists" seem to say that you should never return model elements, and as such, one should create a VM wrapper for each domain object used.

Comment: @PeterDuniho The reason why I'm not doing it that way, is because in the real project, there is no such clear "ownership". To extend the analogy here, suppose there are other model elements (with corresponding view models) that have a reference to player as well (although players do not have a reference back), for example a "PlayersBook" that lists all existing players. When you create the PlayersBookVM you want to create PlayerVMs, but you do not have access to the TeamVM.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. And frankly, if this is not the real example, you should take care to make sure your fake example correctly models _every_ important aspect of the real example. In any case, the view model's job is to represent the model for the view's benefit. Relationships between model objects IMHO can and should be maintained only in the model objects. What is your purpose for having the view model objects preserve those relationships as well? They shouldn't be interacting with each other directly anyway; let the model objects do that.

Comment: _"When you create the PlayersBookVM you want to create PlayerVMs"_ -- why? Why do you need a `PlayerVM` just to create a `PlayersBookVM`? And assuming you do, why can't you just create a `PlayerVM` for that purpose? And if you feel like it's inefficient to create multiple `PlayerVM` objects for the same `Player` object, why don't you just memoize the `PlayerVM` objects, i.e. put them in a dictionary and look them up with the `Player` object as the key? There seems to be a lot unspecified in your question, making it hard to understand or at best, too broad.

Comment: (And I have to admit, while I don't understand this particular question precisely, I am familiar with the headaches involved in trying to follow the strict MVVM pattern. It's why in many of my simper WPF programs, I give up and just conflate the idea of model and view model, i.e. I let my model do the work of the view model as well. In theory, not ideal, but in practice it avoids a lot of the hoop-jumping that's otherwise required.)

Comment: @PeterDuniho Suppose I want to have my PlayerBookVM for my playerbookview. Suppose I want to list all players in a table, with their name. I do this by having playerbookvm create a playervm for each player in the playerbook and then having the grid in my view bind to a property of the playervm. That's what I meant when I said I needed to create PlayerVMs when I want a PlayersbookVM. My comment was a response to comment that suggested I should pass in the TeamVM in the constructor of PlayerVM, which would imply that in order to create a playerbookvm I would need the teamvm as well.

Comment: But that doesn't explain why the `PlayerVM` needs the `TeamVM` reference at all, nor why you can't just pass in `null` when it's unavailable.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thanks.  I'm not sure, OP hasn't really described what he wants in the view

Comment: @PeterDuniho because I may also want to display the team name in that same table.

Comment: I edited the question to include the three basic scenarios that I would want to be supported.

Comment: Why isn't the team name exposed in `PlayerVM`? E.g. `PlayerVM.TeamName`? And if for some reason you want a `PlayerVM` without the team name, then it seems to me you want a _different_ view model e.g. `PlayerBookPlayerVM` for the "player book" scenario, where the team name _is_ exposed.

Comment: I could clone all teamvm properties in player instead of exposing team. But I would prefer not to, as the real case has a lot of properties and I feel this is just a lot of duplication. Then I currently feel my original solution is better as it basically does the same, but simply wrapped in a minimalvm, which is also reused in the full vm. Your suggestion of creating a different vm for a model object based on the view is something I would have to think about. I usually make my domain-VMs to be as complete as possible so that they can cater to all kinds of UI-VMs (for lack of a better term).

Comment: @YvesV. *""purists" seem to say that you should never return model elements"* — You often come to M and VM separation eventually in a complex project, but doing it before it's actually needed is a bad idea — you add complexity and gain nothing in return. Views bound to models is totally fine. Also 1-to-1 relation betwen M and VM, or between V and VM, is overlimplifying architecture decisions, it's not something "automatic".

Answer (score 0):

Your classes have a clear hierarchy: teams aggregate players. Teams are owners, players are owned. Therefore, when creating a player VM, you can pass team VM as a constructor argument.

The obvious limitation of this is now you can't have players without teams. Possible solutions are: enforcing players to always be owned by some team; supporting null as a team VM and setting a proper value later; creating a "null team" object and using it for team-less players.

In cases like these, when there's a clear aggregation hierarchy, I use my [`OwnedObservableCollection<T, TOwner>`](https://github.com/Athari/Alba.Framework/blob/516426e4782659dfb1413c131528e9eb6a754b6d/Alba.Framework/Collections/Collections/OwnedObservableCollection(T).cs). With it, I can create create a collection `_players = new OwnedObservableCollection<PlayerVM, TeamVM>(this)` in a team, then just add and remove players to and from the teams by using just `Add` and `Remove`.

Comment: Referring to my comment above, while it is indeed true that "every player" has a team, the viewmodel is sometimes started with a player. Suppose you have a Playersbook that lists all players in a competition. When you create a playersbookvm, you want to create PlayerVMs without having access to the teamvm. You could theoretically create the teamvms first, but that may not always be needed.